# How to use Shiro for authenticating cookie based or facebook user?

Tags: facebook, apache, security, authentication, shiro

In my web application, I do not have user registrations/login. What I have is the user account is automatically created when the user visits the site first time based on the cookie. How can I use Shiro for this purpose to authenticate such a user ( and also take advantage of its other web security features)?

If the user chooses to login via Facebook connect, then how can I use Shiro for this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after JohnS told me that the linked blog post  doesn't work and some time passed by, I reworked my answer.

In my understanding, Apache Shiro doesn't support (at the time of this writing) OAuth, see [SHIRO-21](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-21) and [SHIRO-119](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-119) and also the comments on them.

There are two libraries which simplifie OAuth, [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) and [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/).

- Scribe is used by [GAEShiro](https://gaeshiro.appspot.com/), which includes a bridge between scribe and Shiro.
- Pac4J is used by [buji-pac4j](https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j), which is a web multi-protocols client for Apache Shiro. On the linked page is a demo with Facebook authentication available, see [here](https://github.com/leleuj/buji-pac4j-demo). I suggest to use this demo as a start.

Please make sure to read [Facebook OAuth 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) and [Server-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)). If you want to enable your site to use OAuth 2.0 then you have to follow the guide on the links.

There is also the mentioned [blog post](http://mrdwnotes.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-apache-shiro-security-to-allow-login-via-facebook-part-1/) and alternatively you can use [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)  and [Spring social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social), see [Signing in with Service Provider Accounts](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html).